# Create scripts from DB project using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I have a requirement where in I need to create seperate script files for procedures, functions and views when we generate the build . We follow the method where we drop all the objects and then re create them again . This happens each time we release the build . Now I need to build a project and extract the SQL files to drop the objects first and then create scripts to create the objects .

Also to be noted whether or not the particular object was modified it needs to be still included in the scripts .

Appreciate if any of you share the approach and the details for achieving the same .

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly using Visual Studio, but Management Studio can easily help you for this. From your project update your dev copy of the database and connect to it with SSMS. Then use [Generate Scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/generate-scripts-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-2017) wizard (right click on the database, Tasks -> Generate scripts...) to generate scripts for your views, procedures and functions:

[image]

On the next page, in Advanced, make sure that `Check for object existance` is set to `True`, `Script DROP and CREATE` is `Script DROP and CREATE` and `Script for Server Version` corresponds to your SQL Server's version (because it may not supports `DROP IF EXISTS`). This will generate you a script to drop and create the objects you selected in the beginning. You can fine-tune the list, if needed, e.g. to exclude some objects.

Comment: Thanks Andrey , And the thing is we have multiple developers who develop the code and modify the objects and check in the changes . So I need it to be done through visual studio for sure . However thanks for your response .

Answer (score 0):

The following C# using `SMO` objects in generating CREATE and DROP scripts.  As you'll notice, the DROP statements are done within the code, while the CREATE DDL is via `SMO`.  This example uses tables, but the same can be done for views, stored procedures, functions etc. by changing the `Table` class (in `foreach` loop) to the type of object that needs to be scripted.  If you decide to take this approach, adding references to `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo`, `System.Collections.Specialized`, `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc`, and `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo` will be needed.  If necessary, the DROP/CREATE statements can as be used as the text for a `SqlCommand` object to further automate this process.

```
                //set server and database
                Server srv = new Server(@"YourServer");
                //to use Windows Authentication
                srv.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = true;

                Database db = srv.Databases["YourDatabase"];

                Scripter script = new Scripter(srv);
                ScriptingOptions scriptOpt = new ScriptingOptions();
                string dropFilePath = @"C:\Test\DROP_SCRIPT_";
                string createFilePath = @"C:\CREATE_SCRIPT_";
                string dropObjPt1 = "IF (OBJECT_ID(N'YourDatabase.YourSchema.";
                string dropObjPt2 = "') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE ";

                //this can changed to views, functions, stored procedures, etc.
                foreach (Table t in db.Tables)
                {
                    //check for system objects
                    //use t.Name to filter table name if needed
                    if (!t.IsSystemObject)
                    {
                        File.WriteAllText(dropFilePath + t.Name + ".sql", dropObjPt1 + t.Name + dropObjPt2 + t.Name);
                    }
                }
                foreach (Table t in db.Tables)
                {
                    if (!t.IsSystemObject)
                    {
                        StringCollection sc = t.Script(scriptOpt);
                        foreach (string s in sc)
                        {
                            File.WriteAllText(createFilePath + t.Name + ".sql", s);
                        }
                    }
                }
```